# Sketchup to Blender to Animated GLTF into Cesium nightmare

Tags: animation, blender, cesiumjs, sketchup, gltf

I would be grateful for some suggestions for best best practice.

I am a proficient user of Sketchup for a dozen years. I can make my way around blender.

I have a need to model a wind turbine which ends up in gltf and imported into cesium with animated blades and orientation (ie. two animations).

Over the last couple of weeks I have learnt how to animate the blades in the correct plane in blender at appropriate revolution speed. I now have an animated model ready for export with seemingly good structure / hierarchy of parts.

If I export to fbx the blade rotation is correct but materials and textures are missing. Plus I can't migrate it to Gltf as every option I try fails.

If I use the gltf exporters from Khronos when running the animation the blades disappear altogether. If I use the other gltf exporter the blade angle gets corrupted (unlike fbx) and no animation survives the export. If I import the fbx back into blender the model is intact (except no materials) and the rotation works as exported. If I export as Collada / dae the blades drop from the top of the model to the bottom and there is no animation.

I have played hours of videos, searched and read endless Web pages but after weeks of effort I have failed to get anywhere near my goal - an animated gltf that I can import into Cesium.

Every step of the way is plagued by imponderable next steps to fix the problem. I have run out of puff.

I would be hugely grateful for some best case suggestions on doing something which seems like it should be simple but simply isn't.

Regards

dawrightau

Comment: Are you able to post the `.blend` file somewhere for us to diagnose? This may require a fix to one or more of the tools you mention.

Comment: Hi Don. would be very happy to send the blend file to you. Would prefer it not be a public model. How can I get it to you.

Comment: Also thanks very much for your reply and offer of assistance. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Let me know if you would like the exported fbx, dae, gltf files which show the various issues / incompatibilites as well.

Comment: Sure, you can email the `.blend` file to `dm@donmccurdy.com` if that's OK.

Comment: Great thanks Don. That's very generous of you. Have sent you an email as offered. Regards David

Comment: Don just wanted to make a public comment to thank you for your help. As you advised by adding a 'bone' to the blades it loads and animates (without materials) in threejs and Babylonjs. Unfortunately however it still won't load in cesium. I am suspicious I still have a badly formed gltf file as it also crashes windows 3D Builder and only the tower section loads in CadAssist. I would be grateful for any more suggestions but thank you for the help you have given. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Alternatively if anyone can suggest how to check within a gltf file and identify where errors are I would be most grateful for this model and trouble  shooting others. If someone can advise on exporting materials from blender to a gltf package of files that would be much appreciated too. Cheers

Comment: The [glTF Validator](http://github.khronos.org/glTF-Validator/) can test for errors.  It's built into Don's [glTF Viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) and is also available offline in the glTF Tools extension for VSCode (I'm a contributor).

Comment: Thanks for your comment emackey. I have tried the validator. In my gltf I get three empty node encountered messages, two "Material does not use texture coordinates sets with indices (0)" and 149 messages "Accessor element at index xxxx is not of unit length: 0." The gltf animated model works in threejs but I cant load it in Cesium. Are these errors likely to be the problem? Can you advise what is the best way / tool to clean the gltf of these errors?